# Show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{e^n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{e^n}$$
$$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp(\ln(\frac{n}{e^n})) $$
$$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp(\ln(ne^{-n})) $$
$$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp(\ln((n^{\frac{-1}{n}}e)^{-n})) $$
$$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp(-n \ln((n^{\frac{-1}{n}}e))) = 0 $$

Is my argument valid?

Comment: All is valid except that the last step ("$=0$") is hardly justified

Comment: How about using L Hopital Rule?

Comment: Your sequence is always positive. You could use the fact that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} < 1$, where $s_n$ is positive, then $s_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: A simpler method would be to prove that $2^n>n^2$ for $n \geq 5$ so $e^n>2^n>n^2$ and this means that $$\frac{n}{e^n}<\frac{1}{n}$$ . The Sandwich theorem now shows that the limit is $0$

Comment: Of course my favourite method would be to use $\exp(x)\ge 1+x$ hence for $n>0$, $\exp(n)=\exp(\frac n2)^2\ge (1+\frac n2)^2$ ...

Comment: How would I justify the last step? I wanted to try and show it without using L'Hospital's Rule. This is going to sound... cyclic?, but I was trying to get it into a form which would make it obvious. (but ... define obvious )

Comment: I think that the form in your proof actually makes it less and less obvious (although the steps are correct leading up to "=0"). There are several nice methods in the comments above that don't need l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: If it was an exam question, I would have used ComplexPhi's method. But I thought I'd try an alternative approach. Thanks anyway guys/girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, your last step is hard to understand & justify. Although it is easy to apply L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form as follows $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{e^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\underbrace{n}_{\large\to \infty}}{\underbrace{e^n}_{\large \to \infty}}$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dn}(n)}{\frac{d}{dn}(e^n)}$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{e^n}$$$$=\frac{1}{\infty}=0$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is; although you might want to read a bit about L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: How is the "=0" justified?